# Gautama maharshi's parents/ancestry

Tags: rishi, ancestry

Who are Gautama maharshi, one of sapta rishis, parents and ancestors linking all the way to Brahma? Are there any stories related to his birth?

Mahabharata describes him as son of Gotama but nothing more, and details his children. Ramayana has story about Ahalya, but little I could find about his ancestors.

Comment: Brahmaji —> Angiras + Svarat (wife) —> Gautama